# How to avoid wrong array-bounds warning on a pointer in g++12?

Tags: c++, g++

For a bare metal app for a Raspberry Pi I have this code:

```
#define UART0_BASE      0x3F201000
void putc(char c) {
  volatile unsigned int *UART0_DR = (volatile unsigned int *)(UART0_BASE);
  volatile unsigned int *UART0_FR = (volatile unsigned int *)(UART0_BASE + 0x18);
  while (*UART0_FR & (1 << 5) ) { }
  *UART0_DR = c;
}
```

When I compile this with g++-12 I get (same for UART0_FR):

```
uart.cc:28:15: warning: array subscript 0 is outside array bounds of ‘volatile unsigned int [0]’ [-Warray-bounds]
   28 |   *UART0_DR = c;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~
```

Note: This is new in g++-12 (trunk on godbolt as of this writing) and 11.2 and before don't show it.

The pointer is not out of bounds and I know that the UART data register is at that place. So how do I tell the compiler the bounds for the pointer?

I'm actually looking for possibly 3 cases:

1. pointer to a single volatile unsigned int
2. pointer to an array of N volatile unsigned int
3. pointer to a struct of volatile unsigned int

All 3 cases would be at a fixed address and not something returned by malloc/new where the compiler knows the bounds.

Update: The warning goes away if the pointer is global or static instead of local. So likely a compiler bug or at least inconsistent.

Comment: @user7860670 memcpy() would result in undefined behavior (of the hardware) as the MMIO register in the hardware MUST be accessed as a 32bit read/write and memcpy() makes no such garantee.

Answer (score 1):

It's a compiler [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104828) with the supposed workaround is to disable the warning for the affected function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here isn't with your code per se, the problem is with C++ permitting very open-ended pointer operations, and newer versions including static analysis tools to try to prevent some common problems that arise from it, which require you to use less open-ended code. For example, you could write your code as follows:

```cpp
#define UART0_BASE      0x3F201000
void putc(char c) {
  volatile unsigned int &UART0_DR = *(volatile unsigned int *)(UART0_BASE);
  volatile unsigned int &UART0_FR = *(volatile unsigned int *)(UART0_BASE + 0x18);
  while (UART0_FR & (1 << 5) ) { }
  UART0_DR = c;
}
```

In the above the pointer is no longer a naked pointer with no length, it's a reference to a length one memory location of type `uint32_t` (which you should definitely be using over your types), so the compiler knows exactly how much memory is safely accessible.

> pointer to an array of N volatile unsigned int

```
// you want to use standard spans here, since they carry both start, type and length information
auto mem = std::span { (unsigned int *)START_ADDRESS, N };
mem[2] = 50;  // read and write as usual
```

> pointer to a struct of volatile unsigned int

If I'm reading this right, it's exactly like the first case, cast it to a reference of your struct. Just make sure to set the packing correctly using `#pragma pack` or your compiler's flavor to match the hardware memory packing.

Again, I want to make sure you understand that the problem isn't with your code as is, it's that the compiler is telling you that if you provide to it additional information (pointer start, type and length, ie a span) it can help you avoid some common problems. It's up to you to decide whether it's worth it or not, but if you want my opinion, naked pointers are always the first place I look at when something isn't working, they cause most problems in C++ code. There are definitely better tools.

Comment: I know the problem isn't my code, other than using implementation defined behavior. :) But your solution doesn't fix anything. I still get a warning on `UART0_DR = c`. Getting an out-of-bound [0] warning on something without * or [] is rather interesting.

Comment: Show me how you're compiling it, I can't reproduce that on trunk godbolt as you said.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/8hjM44qhh   The important part is to use -O2 as array bounds check are part of the optimizing pass.

Comment: Ah, it was `-O2`. Well, I can definitely reproduce it now, both on the reference and on the span. I think it's a bug in gcc, it gets confused by the constant pointer value it can't follow to an actual definition. You should report it to the gcc team.

Comment: I reported it and it got marked as duplicated of a much broader problem of array warnings. The problem seems to be that it runs into the code path that reports pointers that are offsets to NULL. Like `(struct Foo)NULL->blubber`. Will see if they find a fix for it.